# How do I make WiFi calls on my iPad when the IPhone is not accessible?

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi-calling

Per this [Apple support doc](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/make-and-receive-phone-calls-ipadf97892b2/ipados) you should be able to configure your iPhone/iPad pair so you have true WiFi calling and [it] “allows iPad and other devices where you’re signed in with the same Apple ID to make and receive calls **even when your iPhone isn’t nearby**”. (emphasis added)

This has been working for me for years, but I had some mishap with my devices were I logged in/out of my Apple IDs.  Now I cant make/receive calls on my iPad unless it goes through the iPhone.  As soon as the iPhone is not connected to the same WiFi, the iPad won’t do calls.

How can I fix this?  AppleCare was worse than useless.

ETA:
Tried

- sign out of iCloud on both devices, reboot, sign in
- resetting Network
- resetting All Settings

Answer (score 1):

This depends on support from your carrier.  Per the document you linked:

> Note: Wi-Fi Calling on other devices is available with some carriers,
> and cellular charges may apply.

To enable other devices:

> - Tap Wi-Fi Calling, then turn on Add Wi-Fi Calling For Other Devices.
>
> This allows iPad and other devices where you’re signed in with the
> same Apple ID to make and receive calls even when your iPhone isn’t
> nearby.

Comment: This is enabled for my carrier, T-mobile. As I have already said, this worked for years.  I actually got this working, but very temporarily and sporadically.  Be it a network, carrier, or software issue, it has worked and *should* work.